# Tangent space in the book "Differential Forms and Applications"

Tags: geometry, manifolds, definition

In the book "Differential Forms and Applications", the author defines the tangent space of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ at $p$ ($p \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$) as $\mathbb{R}^{3}_{p}=\{q-p; q \in \mathbb{R}^{3}\}$. My question is, this definition coincides with the definition which the tangent space of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ at $p$ is $\mathbb{R}^{3}_{p}=\varphi'(p).\mathbb{R}^{3}$, where $\varphi=Id_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}$? Why the author adopts the first definiton?

Comment: In fact, it's the same as a set. The author just emphasize that in $\Bbb{R}^3_p$, the origin is the point $p\in \Bbb{R}^3,$ i,e., every vector $v\in \Bbb{R}^3_p$ begins in $p.$

Comment: I can't understand the definition with $\varphi' $. The one you cite instead, seems quite transparent

Comment: One of the definitions of tangent space is the image of derivative of parametrization of manifold. In the case th manifold is $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, and thus the  parametrization is $\varphi= Id:\mathbb{R}^{3} \to \mathbb{R}^{3}$, thus $\mathbb{R}^{3}_{p} = \varphi'(p).\mathbb{R}^{3}$